# Publishing a vector of point clouds

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully published pointclouds by converting them to ROSMsg. But is it somehow possible to publish a vector containing multiple pointclouds?

I tried this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<ClassPoint> out;
 ....
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 out_msg;
pcl::toROSMsg(out, out_msg);

std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> clouds(2); 
clouds[0] = out_msg;
out_msg.header.frame_id = corner_frame_name;

pub_merged_clouds.publish(clouds);
```

while I got

```
pub_merged_clouds = nh.advertise<std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>>(merged_clouds_topic, 1);
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. I get the following error when compiling

```
error: ‘const class std::vector<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
     return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks alot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341122/publishing-a-vector-of-point-clouds/) by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-06**:
You need to define a new message type containing an array of pointclouds.

**Comment by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on 2020-01-06**:
@stevemacenski Thank you for you reply. Could you elaborate? How exactly can I create an own sensor_msgs type?

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2020-01-08**:
To add on to @stevemacenski's comment, have a look at [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) . The custom msg will have an array of `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`, e.g. in a `filename.msg`,  `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2[ ] clouds`. Then, in your code  declare `packagename::filename clouds` and `clouds.push_back(cloud)` each cloud. Include the new header file for the custom msg in your code. It would be better to build the new msg package first then your other package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[sensor_msgs::PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) is already defined [sensor message](http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_msgs) but an array of `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` is not. Therefore you will need to define your own custom message. Check the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) on how to create and use a custom message.

Your `.msg` file (for example you can name it `PointClouds.msg`) should look something like this:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2[] pointclouds
```

Once you have created and included your msg, the following should work:

```
#include "your_pkg_name/PointClouds.h"
...
pcl::PointCloud<ClassPoint> out;
 ....
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 out_msg;
pcl::toROSMsg(out, out_msg);

your_pkg_name::PointClouds clouds_msg(2); 
clouds_msg.pointclouds[0] = out_msg; // or just clouds_msg.pointclouds.push_back(out_msg);
out_msg.header.frame_id = corner_frame_name;

pub_merged_clouds.publish(clouds_msg);
```

and your publisher:

```
pub_merged_clouds = nh.advertise<your_pkg_name::PointClouds>(merged_clouds_topic, 1);
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2020-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-08**:
I would also add to think about whether you (ie: @rosNewbie ) actually really need to (or should) publish a set of PointClouds together. If you're doing this because they were "captured at the same time" and you want to publish them together as it would maintain that temporal relationship, then I would suggest using `message_filters` with a time-based synchroniser instead.

No custom message needed, all visualisation tools will remain compatible with what you already have and you still get the same behaviour.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-08**:
I agree with [@gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/). Publishing multiple pointclouds at once is also bad performance-wise. Unfortunately the OP did not provide any additional info on why he needs multiple pointclouds and what does he plan to do with them. All we can infer is that he is publishing them via a `pub_merged_clouds` publisher, which means he wants to merge/process these clouds somewhere else. There are definitely better ways to handle poitcloud data, but looking at the question, it comes down to a beginner lesson of learning how to write custom messages in ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-08**:
Please don't take my comment as criticism @pavel92. I just wanted to provide some additional information.

As-is, this could be an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info). Let's see whether @rosNewbie can clear things up for us with some more information on why he wants to do this.

Your answer is a perfectly fine one (if the question really is: "how do I create a custom message that carries an array/list of other messages").

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-08**:
None taken, it is more for the OP to clarify his intent so we can provide a better solution if it is possible :)

**Comment by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on 2020-01-08**:
@gvdhoorn @pavel92 Thank you both for your help! This really helped. Now I now how to create my own msg type. But as gvdhoorn mentioned it is performance-wise not the best solution. I didn't know about message_filters and will try this. Because this is exactly what I need. I have some pointclouds that have a temporal relationship.